# Can you sum rows from one query's result set and use that total in another query?

Tags: sql, sum

1. I have a query that will sum scores from the top users of a website:

```
SELECT SUM(score) 
FROM hacker_news
GROUP BY user
HAVING score > 200;
```

This produces a result set with 4 rows with 4 integers.

2. I want to sum these 4 rows and divide it by the sum of scores from the entire table.
3. I have tried running it using a subquery and a temporary

any help in writing the simplest query possible would be much appreciated. Ideally I'd like to know if this doable without creating a temporary table and joining

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.  The `HAVING` clause doesn't make sense, because `score` is not defined after the aggregation -- well, unless `user` is the primary key of `hacker_news`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the proportion of totals scores based on those with more than 200, then you can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN score > 200 THEN score ELSE 0 END) / SUM(score) 
FROM hacker_news
```

Comment: can i use that conditional aggregation when its the sum of individual users score? for example, i only want to sum the score if the individual users sum(score) is > 200.